# Car purchase selection App

Tags: comparison, car

I want to buy a new car. I have some strict criteria (like price) but most elements of the car (like milage, acceleration or top speed) are more fluent, so I'd like to know the best ones for my preferences.

Now, there are dozens of manufacturers and dozens of models each having several configuration elements.

I would like to have a Software (Linux Desktop preferred, Windows okay, WebApp okay, Mobile App okay) that allows me to enter the information of the variants that interest me so that I can seriously compare them.

I don't care at all about how that car looks like but all the brochures of the manufacturers seem to focus mostly on that.

Big Bonus if the app already has the information from the vendor inserted.

I'm willing to pay up to 100€ for the app if it already has the information (or if its a WebApp can share the infos between the users so not everybody has to enter all the stuff every time).

20€ if I have to insert all the data myself.

I need to be able to compare:

- milage

  - for gas, LPG, electro, hybrids of them (maybe by measuring km/50€)
- price

  - for the first year, including complete payment for purchase of car
  - for ten years, including consumption of fuel
  - optionally: for mandatory service and expected repairs
- optionally CO2 production

  - would be nice if that includes the production cost

Optionally give an "how important is it" mark so that the cars can be sorted by this. (Like low CO2: Very important, Automatic gearing: Nice to have, Price for 10 years: important)

Comment: What about engine size? I only mention becuase that often detremines your insurance group, which affects the price of insurance. Notet that for "consumption of fuel" you will have to estiamte ditance travelled, where it is in town or country, etc. Also, do you car if it is only a 2 seater? Do tyres matter (over 10 years)? I liiiiiike this question & hope for an answer.

Comment: @Mawg Well, I would not have thought about that, but yeah. Sounds relevant, should be included. "consumption of fuel" of course needs an estimate on how far I travel. Since I wrote this question I started thinking about writing this application. I wonder how much I could charge for it...

Comment: Car is wheels and a roof. The Twizy counts as car in my world (as soon at has doors and windows)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found such a webapp. Its in German though. It can be found here: [ADAC New Car Recommendations](https://www.adac.de/infotestrat/fahrzeugkauf-und-verkauf/neuwagenberater/default.aspx). The [ADAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADAC) is the German club of car owners.

It works exactly like I would have liked it: I can select the elements that I need and place some preferences (like "Long Range Quality", "Transport capability") in a range from "I don't care" to "Super important".

Then the tool produces a list of cars that meet that criteria.

Of course the app, being German, focuses on the German market and the prices to be paid in Germany. If you find a similar app in your country from your car club feel free to add it.

I've used this app to select the cars that are interesting to me and am now test driving them to make the final decision. So, in the end I used this app and an own spreadsheet that reduced the amount of information to the ones that I care about and some calculations about my own usage. I would give this app 3 out of 5 points. It really needs a calculation part where I can enter my usage and my relevant criteria more detailed so that I don't have to use my own spreadsheet for that.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some recommendations for ***Great Britain***, which lead you step by step, through the various options mentioned in the question, to a selection of possibilities.

- http://www.topgear.com/uk/car-chooser-launch    (yay!! Top Gear !!)
- http://www.carbuyer.co.uk/car-finder  (good selection criteria)
- https://www.carwow.co.uk/car-chooser (slighlty less selection & misses the low priced models)

see also:

- http://www.which.co.uk/cars/choosing-a-car/buying-a-car/car-comparison/  (good, independent, consumer advice source for half a century or more)

Comment: I don't think we are bending the rules here, but just to clarify I made a meta for it: http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/1246/94

Comment: A good point. Hopefully an discussion can continue there.

Comment: Seems like the community deems this Q&A as being an app, so I removed the parts of your answer that questioned that.